# Inheritance and identifying object types in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, abstract

Okay, so I'm working on a project with abstract class A. Let's say that class a1, a2, and a3 all inherit from class A with some additional methods that may be unique to each subclass. Now, these objects can be paired with other objects as a result of user interaction, but only certain types of objects can be paired, ie, object B can only use a1, object C can only use a2, and an attempt by the user to pair them otherwise results in telling them that they can't. I would certainly like to avoid instanceof as it's largely bad practice, but I think I have a rather nasty case of cerebral flatulence at the moment. I thought of adding a getType() or some such method in the parent class to return a string unique to each subclass, but that feels hackneyed. Grabbing the class name feels much the same. I'm a bit rusty on my OO and polymorphism principles, so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't see any problem for using instanceof on this case, it is considered a bad practice when you use it to check types on runtime when they should be checked at compile time, but you say that it is the user who will do the pairing (hence runtime operation) so  instanceof seems like a good choice

Answer (score 2):

If you're really set on not using instanceof, and you can't, for whatever reason, define the parameter for the pairing beyond the instance class, add to the abstract class a set new methods that do one of two things:

a) the method worksWithTypeB, worksWithTypeC, and so on, defining them in the subclasses as appropriate.  This is much like typechecking, however.

b) transfer the methods that will be used by types B and C to the abstract class; define them normally in the classes which can be used by B and C (so let's say that type B uses a1.methodB, and type C uses a2.methodC), but define them to throw an exception that in the methods that wouldn't exist otherwise (so a1.methodC throws an exception, as does a2.methodB).

Although as ilcavero said, there isn't really anything wrong with typechecking in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking in a solution by using generics for this case.

To do this you will need to define a class that stores two values genericly like

class Pair < k, v extends A>

now you would be adding to an hashmap all type of pairs you can have. When a pair of that type is needed you would get the pair by its name.

Cons:

You have to add to the container all wanted pairs

You have to associate a pair a name

Note that in a huge scale this would be a bad solution.